Google Meet Add On -- deployment is invalid
I'm trying to create a Google Meet add-on by following the instructions here
http://developers.google.com/meet/add-ons/guides/build-add-on
When I build the manifest / deployment file using their tool and try to add it in the API / service details screen I get
There was an error creating the deployment: the provided deployment is invalid

Here's my file (URL's changed but I know the real ones exist)
{
  "addOns": {
    "common": {
      "name": "My Awesome Add On",
      "logoUrl": "https://www.awesomeaddon.com/logo.png"
    },
    "meet": {
      "web": {
        "sidePanelUri": "https://www.awesomeaddon.com/addon",
        "supportsScreenSharing": false,
        "logoUrl": "https://www.awesomeaddon.com/logo.png",
        "addOnOrigins": ["https://www.awesomeaddon.com/addon"]
      }
    }
  }
}

What can I do to chase this down?
